# Left join with complicated where clause

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables: zones and reservations

```
zones
-----
id:int
name:varchar
slots:int

reservations
------------
zone:int
timestamp:long
```

And I need to get all zones with the number of active reservations (reservations with timestamp smaller than reftimestamp shouldn't count as active).

**EDIT**
OK With this query, I am getting a better result:

```
SELECT z.name, count(r.timestamp) 
    FROM zonas AS z 
    LEFT JOIN reservations AS r 
    ON z.id = r.zona 
    WHERE r.timestamp > $refTimestamp
    GROUP BY z.id
```

But I want to get all zones. Even if there is no reservation on the other table, it should return the zone with a zero (0) on count(r.timestamp)

How do I do that?

Comment: And, what exactly is it missing? How are your results different from what you expect?

Comment: Try `ON z.id = r.zona AND r.timestamp > $reftimestamp`. I guess You are missing zones, that have zero reservations in Your result?

Comment: @David Lively it just doesn't work (count(r.*))

Comment: What is your RDBMs ? It seems MySql by the `z.*` and `group by z.id` as it is the only one that allows this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is this:

```
SELECT z.name, 
       sum(case when r.timestamp is null then 0 
                when r.timestamp > $refTimestamp then 1
                else 0 end)
  FROM zonas AS z 
  LEFT JOIN reservations AS r 
    ON z.id = r.zona 
 GROUP BY z.id
```

This will get you all zones.

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c37e8/1

Comment: same result... if there is no reservation row associated to a zone, the zone just won't appear :/

Comment: @SebastianBreit fixed it. try it now please

Comment: Sorry by the time I ask you to test it, there was a typo error, I pasted the solution without removing the wrong version. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT z.*, count(r.*) 
FROM zonas AS z 
LEFT JOIN reservations AS r 
ON z.id = r.zona 
AND r.timestamp > $reftimestamp
GROUP BY z.id
```

As You can see, I moved the `WHERE` condition into `LEFT JOIN ... ON`. In Your case, database first executes the left join - the rows, that had no reservation, have `NULL` as their timestamp, so they cannot make it through the `WHERE` condition (because `NULL > whatever` is false).

See similar fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124cc7/5

Comment: Thanks but this will only give me the zones for which there is at lease one reservation. If there is no reservation for a zone, it wont appear with this query.